# Lightning Component: Link to an attachment in Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Usually to show an Image saved as an attachment we do the below:

```
/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j0000001VxweAAC
```

The same doesn't work in Communities unless you add the UrlPathPrefix which varies from community to community. I can get the UrlPathPrefix from the Apex and add it to the url. But right now I've that link to an image in a block of content wherein I've multiple images along with text - saved into TextArea field. I was wondering how can we do this in lightning component? something like `$Resource (URLFOR)`!